# My Python function 'loops' for no reason

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, loops

I'm writing a Python function to collect user input and then return it as a dict.
The input should meet certain criteria, so I check for that and I ask the user to supply his input again if it doesn't check out.
This is my code:

```
def getIDs(stageid=0):
    if stageid == 0:
        stageid = input("Please supply stageID: ")
        if (len(stageid) < 4 or len(stageid) > 5) or not stageid.isdigit():
            print("Wrong stageID, try again.")
            getIDs()
    raceid = input("Please supply the raceID: ")
    if (len(raceid) < 1 or len(raceid) > 3) or not raceid.isdigit():
        print("Wrong raceID, try again.")
        getIDs(stageid)
    else:
        # print(stageid)
        return {"stageid": stageid, "raceid": raceid}
```

What I do is have the function just call itself if the stageid isn't correct, but I don't want the user to have to re-enter the stageid again if the raceid is incorrect, so if the raceid is incorrect, the I call the function with the stageid as a parameter.
My problem is, however, that if I get the stageid wrong several times, then get it right and continue to the raceid, it will ask for the raceid for as many times as I had entered the stageid. I can't figure out why. The commented print function prints all supplied stageid's in reverse order and in the end, the return value contains the initially supplied (wrong) stageid and the raceid.

Does anybody know why Python somehow loops through all values?

Vasilis

Comment: Your indentation is broken, please fix it.

Comment: And the answer is that the function doesn't "restart", it just calls itself as a recursive function. Once it's finished, it continues execution from the `getIDs()` call. This could be fixed, but this approach is very inadequate for python.

Comment: Using recursion in this case will almost guarantee you headaches, but you should know that if you do not `return getIDs()` your outer-most call of getID's will return `None`

Comment: @ettanany I would suggest against editing python whitespace in questions. I know in this case this is probably correct since OP is not complaining about indentation errors, but still, worth being cautious.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I agree with you that when OP complains about indentation we should not edit the code, but in this case, I think it is clear.

Comment: I've used recursive functions like this before, which never gave me problems. Is it because I return two values that I get into trouble?

Comment: No, it's because your recursive calls are not captured. Noting gets updated, and they all finish execution, which is why for every time you enter stageid you have to enter a raceid

Comment: With regards to your indentation, when you posted your function you lost the indent after `def getIDs(...`

Comment: And you aren't returning two values, you are returning a single value.

Comment: OK, but then it's still related to the number of variables I process.

Comment: Yes, I just figured out the indentation problem. I didn't see it at first because it was already fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a return statement when calling the recursive function so the termination will exit from that instance.

```
def getIDs(stageid=0):
    if stageid == 0:
        stageid = input("Please supply stageID: ")
        if (len(stageid) < 4 or len(stageid) > 5) or not stageid.isdigit():
            print("Wrong stageID, try again.")
            return getIDs()
    raceid = input("Please supply the raceID: ")
    if (len(raceid) < 1 or len(raceid) > 3) or not raceid.isdigit():
        print("Wrong raceID, try again.")
        return getIDs(stageid)
    else:
        # print(stageid)
        return {"stageid": stageid, "raceid": raceid}
```